# Do you need a computer to use a Chromecast?

Tags: desktop-computer, tv, chromecast, netflix

Does a Chromecast require a computer to use it? Do you need a computer to set up a Chromecast?

Can I stream Netflix with only the Chromecast, an HDMI TV, wall power, a Google account, a Netflix account, and an Internet connection?

Comment: Since obviously the SuperUser community thinks this question is off-topic for SuperUser, I've proposed a new SE site for Google products here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/115799/google

Comment: All the info you need is Googleable https://store.google.com/product/chromecast_2015

Comment: Nope. "Simply use your device and the TV you own to stream TV shows, movies, games and more." Is "your device" the Chromecast or a computer? "Chromecast works with iPhone®, iPad®, Android phone and tablet, Mac® and Windows® laptop and Chromebook." Is this for using it or for setting it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address this in two parts setup and use.

**Setup:**
As far as setting up the Google Chromecast it can be done from a computer. However this is only possible from a recent version of Google Chrome: Link

Secondly this interface does tend to be buggier than using the Google Home app on say an Android phone.

**Use:**
Googles Chromecasts aren't like a Smart TV, Roku, or Blu Ray they don't have remotes they actually use a phone or computer to be controlled. For example Netflix you just pull up the app click the little cast icon and it begins playback on the Chromecast regardless of if you then turn your device off or not.

Basically what this boils down to is answering your first question, no you don't need a computer to use a Google Chromecast but you do need a device that is compatible (ideally an Android phone). To answer your second question no without a device to control it a Chromecast is a really nice $35 paper weight.

This is described in the small print quoted below.

> ²Chromecast, Chromecast Ultra, Chromecast Audio require: a TV with an HDMI port, a Wi-Fi network and a compatible (Android, iOS, Windows or Mac OS) computer or mobile device. Minimum OS requirements are at g.co/cast/req. Availability and performance of features and services (including 4K and screen mirroring) are application, device and network-dependent and may not be available in all areas. More information is available on the Chromecast Help Center. Chromecast Ultra requires a 4K-capable HDTV and a high-speed broadband internet connection to view 4K content; see g.co/cast/req for minimum broadband requirements. 4K programming is subject to availability from content providers. Chromecast Audio requires speaker with AUX, RCA or optical digital input. iPhone®, iPad® and Mac® are trademarks of Apple Inc., registered in the U.S. and other countries. Windows® is a registered trademark of Microsoft Corporation in the U.S. and other countries.

Source: https://store.google.com/product/chromecast_2015_learn